# can't share an archive in Xcode due to missing icon\r file

Tags: xcode

I put my Xcode project within my dropbox folder and now it seems like every time i try to share my archive from within the organizer it keep giving me the following error:

```
error: Codesign check fails : /var/folders/7l/l93zzs6n4h14qb7rmj5r7zn00000gn/T/GtLyx05w1O/Payload/stryker.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
In architecture: armv6
resource added: /private/var/folders/7l/l93zzs6n4h14qb7rmj5r7zn00000gn/T/GtLyx05w1O/Payload/stryker.app/www/Icon
resource missing: /private/var/folders/7l/l93zzs6n4h14qb7rmj5r7zn00000gn/T/GtLyx05w1O/Payload/stryker.app/www/Icon
```

I believe this error is caused by the fact that Xcode can see the icon/r file associated with drop box.

Is there a way i can delete this file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to share my archive after I deleted the icon\r file.  Please refer to the following post for more info

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31867/what-is-icon-r-file-and-how-do-i-delete-them/31877#31877